# restrict user to libarary tab in media file selector in media module

Tags: 7, files, nodes, media

I want use `media file selector`  as image field in content type . media module provides it to select and upload image by popup, but I dont want user can upload image ,I just want only user can select file from library tab in `media file selector`.
any body know how can I achieve this job?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent user(s) from uploading files, remove the following permission from their role (admin/people/permissions)

> edit media

For the role to still be able to access the library of media that has already been uploaded, ensure that they still have the permission

> Import media files from the local filesystem

Comment: yes, I founded my question before you say, but tnx ;)

Comment: do you know how can I change image style of images in media libarary?

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/97326/change-image-size-in-media-file-selector-of-media-module